# JQuery ReplaceWith() function confusion

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am trying to do a replaceWith().  My Statement looks like this -->  `$("div.ms-quickLaunch").replaceWith("http://wwcshare/icenter/config/wwcMenuControl.html");`

Can I replace a `div` like that?  right now it just puts the text there, "http://wwcshare/icenter/con....".

How do I embed the contents of `wwcMenuControl.html` where the **div** `ms-quickLaunch` resides?

Comment: `http://wwcshare` to `http://wwcshare/icenter` be in abuse of the **same origin policy**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to load the contents of the URL into the div then you can use:

```
 $("div.ms-quickLaunch").load("http://wwcshare/icenter/config/wwcMenuControl.html");
```

Which uses AJAX to fetch the data at the URL and put it into your DIV.

However, there are restrictions for AJAX so the URL has to be from the same domain as the page.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  It no longer puts the text line but it doesn't put anything else either.

Comment: Is the URL that you are loading on the same domain as the containing page?

Comment: This may be a very ignorant quetion but is `http://wwcshare` the same domain as `http://wwcshare/icentr`?

Comment: @Refracted Paladin Yes. It does appear to be the same domain. There might be some other reason the content is not showing up.

Comment: I would suggest that you install firebug for firefox and use that to see what happens when the javascript executes. It should be able to show you the return data from the AJAX call if it succeeds. Then you may be able to tell why nothing shows up.

Comment: The other thing is, from the example that you posted you seem to be trying to include an entire HTML document inside the div of the first document. That may not be the best idea. Can you create a snippet of HTML in the file wwcMenuControl.html? If you absolutely need JavaScript to execute in the included page then you may have to consider using live() function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to load() method

http://api.jquery.com/load/

`Replacewith()` inserts the string value you pass

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) so:

```
$("div.ms-quickLaunch").load("http://wwcshare/icenter/config/wwcMenuControl.html");
```

or

```
$("div.ms-quickLaunch").replaceWith($.get("http://wwcshare/icenter/config/wwcMenuControl.html"));
```

Note that there is a [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) enforced by most browsers so I am assuming that the site you are on is the same as the site you are getting the data from.

Comment: The `$.get()` version generates an error.  Just says "unspecified error" in the jquery 1.4.4 min library.